# Displaying different include file based on logged in status

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to include a different navigation menu for users that are logged in but seem to be having trouble. I'm currently setting a session when a user successfully authenticates, that session then sets a session variable so we know if the user is logged in or logged out.

If they are logged in, they should see the logged in menu, otherwise they should just see the logged out menu. For some reason i cannot get this to work through checking if the user is logged in - not sure what i'm doing wrong.

index.php

```
<?php

require_once("inc/config.php");
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");

session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Property Rental</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <header role="banner" id="top" class="navbar navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <nav role="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="../getting-started">Menu Item 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../css">Menu Item 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../components">Menu Item 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../javascript">Menu Item 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../customize">Menu Item 5</a>
                    </li>

                    <?php

                    if ( $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) { 
                        include("inc/logged.php");
                    } else {
                        include("inc/loggedOut.php");
                    }

                    print_r($_SESSION);

                    ?>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">

        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/core.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

users.database.php

```
<?php 

$username = $_POST['username'];          
$password = $_POST['password'];

try {   

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT username, pass FROM user_info WHERE username = :user AND BINARY pass = :pass");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->bindParam(':pass', $password);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not retrieve data from database";
    exit();
}

if ($password = $rows) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "Username or password incorrect (passwords are case sensitive)";
    }
}

?>
```

logged.php

```
<li class="login-register pull-right">
<ul>
    <li class="login pull-left">
        <a href="#">My Account</a>
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-box-inner">
                <a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

loggedOut.php

```
<li class="login-register pull-right">
<ul>
    <li class="login pull-left">
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <a href="/logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-box-inner">
                <div class="up-arrow"></div>
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username or Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password">
                    </div>

                    <?php require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/users.database.php"); ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label class="remember-me">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </li>
    <span class="slash">/</span>
    <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="/register">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Try print_r($_SESSION); - what does that show? Having done this pretty recently, I would guess $loggedin is not set to true for whatever reason.

Comment: It appears the session is being set, it looks like this to be precise; `Array ( [username] => Maverick2k [logged_in] => 1 [loggedin] => 1 [loggedIn] => 1 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$loggedin` is not being set in your index.php file.

Replace your if condition with this:

```
 if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
```

You can also use this which has the exact same meaning...

```
 if ( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) {
```

With the above code, you are going to need to start a session on that page with `session_start();`

If you are using javascript to go back in the history when a user logs in, change it to this...

```
<script>
    window.location.href = document.referrer;
</script>
```

**NOTE:** This will only go back one page in the history.